# Webscraping <span> into div class

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to access a  inside a class in webscraping, but without success. I need to return the number '597', as image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F990H.png)

The error return is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRZdT.png)

Code

```
url_base = 'https://shopping.smiles.com.br/telefones-e-celulares/magazine-luiza/magazineluiza?initialMap=seller&initialQuery=magazineluiza&map=category-1,sellername,seller'
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
executable_path = r'C:\Users\vinig\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path)
browser.get(url_base)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
qtd_itens = soup.find('class', attrs={'class':"shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-totalProducts--layout pv5 ph9 bn-ns bt-s b--muted-5 tc-s tl t-action--small"}).text()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pure selenium for this. Use `.find_element` and `WebDriverWait` to wait until the elements appears.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url_base = 'https://shopping.smiles.com.br/telefones-e-celulares/magazine-luiza/magazineluiza?initialMap=seller&initialQuery=magazineluiza&map=category-1,sellername,seller'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url_base)

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-totalProducts--layout")))

print(element.text)

browser.quit()
```

Outputs:

```
590 Produtos
```

Comment: Incrible! Tks @Jurakin